# How do you stop all buttons on the oculus touch controller from triggering Aframe links?

Tags: javascript, aframe

Aframe links in the oculus quest are triggered anytime I touch a button on my oculus touch controllers because all capacitance events seem to emit the click event. I am using a raycaster on my controllers.

I have set  "on" in the link attribute to "triggerdown", but I do not think that works because I am using the raycaster, which I believe emits the click event from any event from the controller.

Here is an example of a link:

```html
<a-entity link="href: link.html; title: title; image: #sunrise; visualAspectEnabled: true; on: triggerdown;" position="3.5 1 0" rotation="0 90 0" ></a-entity>
```

When using these settings, my links do not work when I pull the trigger.

When I use the default link settings, any button on the controller I place my fingers triggers the link.

Answer (score 0):

The events that emit a `click` event is determined by the `cursor`'s `downEvents` and `upEvents` property. It should not be triggering for every button unless you have it set to `buttondown` and `buttonup`. What are your `cursor` component's properties attached to the controller?

Comment: I am using laser controls and other custom components to control behavior and look of the raycaster. I have not configured anything for the cursor. Also, any true button press (like clicking the grip) also triggers the link.